# Modifying List contained in Object inside ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I am using a Map to store customer's basket items in-memory. My map has the following signature `Map<Integer, Basket> customerBaskets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

Each `Basket` class has a list of items defined as `Collection<Item> items = new ArrayList<>()`.

During the app startup all the customers loaded into the map and an empty basket is assigned to them. Now I would like to add items to the customer's basket in a thread-safe manner.
Since `ConcurrentHashMap` reads are not locking, I could get the Basket based on customerId and freely add items to the `items` list, this doesn't guarantee me thread safety. How can I ensure thread-safety for writes to this list and reads have the latest written value? Please advise.

Thank You.

Comment: Is this for a production code or simply a learning exercise?

Comment: Probably the most straightforward way is to have the lists created with `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Indeed I did that. But the list resulting out of Collections.synchronizedList() can only save us from concurrent writes. In order to read the list to make sure we have the automacity in place, I had to wrap the iterating over list inside a synchronized block. Just wondering if that is efficient or not or if there is a better way.

Comment: No, there isn't really a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You need either to synchronize the read-write operations on the ArrayList using something like ReentrantLock or use CopyOnWriteArrayList implementation for this underlying array.

Comment: I tried to use a `Collections.synchorizedList()`. I did the following but wondering if it is correct or even efficient.


The declaration: `private final Collection<Item> items = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Item>());`


Writes: `this.items.add(new Item())`


Reads: `synchronized (this.items) {
            Iterator<Item> iterator = this.items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {}}`